# Print Text or HTML to PDF without changing default printer and using Microsoft Print To PDF and no user prompts

Tags: vb.net

I have a need to PDF print the body of an email, text or html, without human intervention and without changing the default printer.

I have answered my own question using pieces from StackOverflow and Microsoft.  The answer is not perfect but it does work for me.  Part of this sharing is to get some feedback on a better way to do this and provide an answer (maybe not the best one) to someone else problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Usage
'Dim printpdf As New PrintToPDF
'printpdf.HTMLToPDF(filecontents, PDFfilename)
'or
'printpdf.TextToPDF(filecontents, PDFfilename)

Imports System.Drawing 'if not used in a form
Imports System.Windows.Forms 'if not used in a form
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class PrintToPDF

Public Property PDFPrinterName As String = "Microsoft Print to PDF"  
Public Property TextPrintFont As Font = New Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
Public Property SaveImagesOfPages As Boolean = False
Public Property SaveImagesOfPagesPath As String = "c:\temp"
Public Property SaveImagePageName As String = "testemail"
''' <summary>
''' Get or Set the color of the margin.  The padded space around the image of the captured HTML
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Property ImageBorderColor As Color = Color.White


Private _PDFMargin As Margins = New Margins(20, 20, 20, 20)
''' <summary>
''' Get or Set printer margin spacing
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Property PDFMargin As Margins
    Get
        Return _PDFMargin
    End Get
    Set(value As Margins)
        _PDFMargin = value
    End Set
End Property


Private _PixelMargin As Integer = 5
''' <summary>
''' Get or Set the margin (ALL) added to the document to provide clean print edges for converting HTML or RTF.
''' Must be a positive integer
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Property PixelMargin As Integer
    Get
        Return _PixelMargin
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If value < 1 Then value = 1
        _PixelMargin = value
        _PaperHeight = PDFPaperSize.Height - (2 * PixelMargin) 'x2 for L/R and T/B
        _PaperWidth = PDFPaperSize.Width - (2 * PixelMargin) 'x2 for L/R and T/B
    End Set
End Property

Private _PDFPaperSize As PaperSize = New PaperSize("Letter", 850, 1100)
Public Property PDFPaperSize As PaperSize
    Get
        Return _PDFPaperSize
    End Get
    Set(value As PaperSize)
        _PDFPaperSize = value
        _PaperHeight = PDFPaperSize.Height - (2 * PixelMargin) 'x2 for L/R and T/B
        _PaperWidth = PDFPaperSize.Width - (2 * PixelMargin) 'x2 for L/R and T/B
    End Set
End Property


'A polling variable to determine when the print job has completed
Private _PrintingComplete As Boolean = False

Private _PrintPDF As PrintDocument
Private _webControl As WebBrowser
Private _WEBControl_BMP As Bitmap = Nothing

Private _BMP_YOffset As Integer = 0 ' The variable that moves the bmp page/image down to the next segment/page
Private _BMP_PageCount As Integer = 1 
Private _BMP_RemainingHeight As Integer = 0

Private _rftControl As RichTextBox
Private _RTFControl_BMP As Bitmap = Nothing

Private _TXT_PageCount As Integer = 1
Private _TextToPrint As String = ""

'just less than the 1100 for a letter so that it doesnt cut off so harse at the edge of a page
Private _PaperHeight As Integer = 1100 
Private _PaperWidth As Integer = 850 

Public Sub New()

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' For development.  Does not work for TextToPDF
''' </summary>
''' <param name="SavePages"></param>
''' <param name="SavePagesPath"></param>
''' <param name="SavePageName"></param>
Public Sub New(ByVal SavePages As Boolean, ByVal SavePagesPath As String, ByVal SavePageName As String)
    _SaveImagesOfPages = SavePages
    _SaveImagesOfPagesPath = SavePagesPath
    _SaveImagePageName = SavePageName
End Sub

#Region "HTML"

''' <summary>
''' Prints an image of rendered HTML to PDF
''' </summary>
''' <param name="HTMLCode"></param>
''' <param name="SaveToPDFFile"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Function HTMLToPDF(ByVal HTMLCode As String, ByVal SaveToPDFFile As String) As Boolean
    Dim rtnBool As Boolean = False
    'Dim printPDF As New PrintDocument
    Try
        _PrintingComplete = False
        If (SaveImagesOfPagesPath <> "") AndAlso (Not SaveImagesOfPagesPath.EndsWith("\")) Then SaveImagesOfPagesPath += "\"

        _webControl = New WebBrowser 'give me a new instance for this event

        _PrintPDF = New PrintDocument
        With _PrintPDF
            .DocumentName = "docHTMLCode" 'give it something for a name, you can see this in the print spooler as the job runs
            .PrintController = New Printing.StandardPrintController
            .DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = False
            .DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = PDFPaperSize 'New PaperSize("Letter", 850, 1100) '.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(PaperKind.Letter) 'New PaperSize("Legal", 850, 1400)
            '_PaperHeight = .DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height
            '.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution = .PrinterSettings.PrinterResolutions(1)
            .DefaultPageSettings.Color = True
            .DefaultPageSettings.Margins = PDFMargin 'not currently being followed, that's why the HTMLInjectMargin was created

            .PrinterSettings.Copies = 1
            .PrinterSettings.PrinterName = _PDFPrinterName '"Microsoft Print to PDF"
            .PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = True
            .PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = SaveToPDFFile
        End With

        Dim pageBottom As Integer = 1

        With _webControl
            .ClientSize = New Size(_PaperWidth, _PaperHeight) 'give it some place to start
            .DocumentText = "0"
            .Document.OpenNew(True)
            .Document.Write(HTMLCode)
            .Refresh() 'let the new html load
            While .ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
                Application.DoEvents()
            End While

            'make the size the same as an even number of full sheets of paper
            pageBottom = .Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height - (_PixelMargin * 2) 'this is the length of the page as it was given
            'now make the page long enough to be a full sheet of paper
            If (pageBottom <= _PaperHeight) Then
                '1 page and short
                pageBottom = _PaperHeight
            Else
                'multiple pages
                pageBottom = (((pageBottom \ _PaperHeight) + 1) * _PaperHeight)
            End If

            'changes the viewable size of the control
            .ClientSize = New Size(_PaperWidth, pageBottom) 'now the client size is the same as X full sheets of paper
            .Refresh() 'redraw so we can get a proper image capture, just in case
        End With

        'with everything set, do the print
        AddHandler _PrintPDF.PrintPage, AddressOf WebControlPrintPage
        AddHandler _PrintPDF.EndPrint, AddressOf WebControlEndPrint
        _BMP_PageCount = 1 'give it a start page

        'set some bounds for the big picture
        _WEBControl_BMP = New Bitmap(_webControl.Bounds.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth, _webControl.Bounds.Height) '_webControl.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom)
        _webControl.DrawToBitmap(_WEBControl_BMP, _webControl.Bounds) 'fill those bounds with an image
        _BMP_RemainingHeight = _WEBControl_BMP.Height 'after this, this height will start being subtracted
        'Debug.Print("_webControl.Bounds.Width : " & _webControl.Bounds.Width.ToString & "  _webControl.Bounds.Height : " & _webControl.Bounds.Height.ToString)
        If SaveImagesOfPages Then Image.FromHbitmap(_WEBControl_BMP.GetHbitmap).Save(SaveImagesOfPagesPath & "FullPage_" & _SaveImagePageName & ".png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

        _PrintPDF.Print() 'this creates the actual pdf file from the PrintPage/WebControlPrint event

        rtnBool = True
        Stall(1) 'buy some time.  noticed that even at this point, after the print, the calling function is unable to access the pdf just created as it is "busy"

        'clean up
        _webControl.Dispose()
        _PrintPDF.Dispose()
        _WEBControl_BMP.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    Return rtnBool
End Function

Private Sub WebControlEndPrint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintEventArgs) 'Handles _PrintPDF.EndPrint
    _PrintingComplete = True
    'Stall(1)
End Sub

Private Sub WebControlPrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs) 'Handles _PrintPDF.PrintPage
    'Dim rtnBool As Boolean = False
    Try

        'e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel 'make the print super small and unreadable
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality

        'Dim destRect As RectangleF
        Dim endOfPage As Integer = 0
        Dim HasMorePages As Boolean = False

        endOfPage = (_PaperHeight * _BMP_PageCount)

        'Debug.Print("0, " & _BMP_YOffset.ToString & ", " & _WEBControl_BMP.Width.ToString & ", " & (endOfPage - _BMP_YOffset).ToString)
        If (_BMP_RemainingHeight > _PaperHeight) Then 'more pages to print
            'multipage
            HasMorePages = True
        Else
            HasMorePages = False
        End If

        Dim srcRect As RectangleF = New RectangleF(0, _BMP_YOffset, _WEBControl_BMP.Width, (endOfPage - _BMP_YOffset)) 'region that should represent the location on the pdf to place the image
        Dim b As Bitmap = _WEBControl_BMP.Clone(srcRect, _WEBControl_BMP.PixelFormat) 'the segment to print

        Dim img As Image = AppendBorder(Image.FromHbitmap(b.GetHbitmap), PixelMargin)

        If SaveImagesOfPages Then img.Save(SaveImagesOfPagesPath & _SaveImagePageName & "_Page_" & _BMP_PageCount.ToString & ".png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, e.MarginBounds) 

        _BMP_YOffset += _PaperHeight 'hold this value for the next run
        _BMP_PageCount += 1

        _BMP_RemainingHeight -= _PaperHeight 'remove a page worth of information
        e.HasMorePages = HasMorePages

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    'on exit clears the print spooler queue
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Extracts text from HTML code
''' </summary>
''' <param name="HTMLCode"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Function HtmlToPlainText(ByVal HTMLCode As String) As String
    Dim rtnText As String = ""
    Try
        Dim webControl As New WebBrowser
        webControl.DocumentText = "0"
        webControl.Document.OpenNew(True)
        webControl.Document.Write(HTMLCode)
        webControl.Refresh()
        'ExecCommand is supposed to be being deprecated soon, will have to come up with something different soon
        webControl.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", False, Nothing)
        webControl.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", False, Nothing)
        webControl.Dispose()
        webControl = Nothing
        rtnText = Clipboard.GetText
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    Return rtnText
End Function

#End Region

#Region "TEXT"
''' <summary>
''' Prints the text to a PDF file
''' </summary>
''' <param name="TextToPrint"></param>
''' <param name="SaveToPDFFile"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Function TextToPDF(ByVal TextToPrint As String, ByVal SaveToPDFFile As String) As Boolean
    Dim rtnBool As Boolean = False
    Try
        _PrintingComplete = False
        _TextToPrint = TextToPrint
        _PrintPDF = New PrintDocument
        With _PrintPDF
            .DocumentName = "docText" 'name shown in the print spooler
            .PrintController = New Printing.StandardPrintController
            .DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = False
            .DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = PDFPaperSize 
            .DefaultPageSettings.Color = True
            .DefaultPageSettings.Margins = PDFMargin 

            .PrinterSettings.Copies = 1
            .PrinterSettings.PrinterName = _PDFPrinterName
            .PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = True
            .PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = SaveToPDFFile
        End With

        'with everything set, do the print
        AddHandler _PrintPDF.PrintPage, AddressOf TextPrintPage
        AddHandler _PrintPDF.EndPrint, AddressOf TextEndPrint
        _TXT_PageCount = 1 'give it a start page

        _PrintPDF.Print() 'this creates the actual pdf file from the PrintPage/WebControlPrint event

        rtnBool = True

        Stall(1) 'buy some time.  noticed that even at this point, after the print, the calling function is unable to access the pdf just created as it is "busy"

        'clean up
        _PrintPDF.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    Return rtnBool
End Function

Private Sub TextPrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)
    '_TextToPrint
    Dim charactersOnPage As Integer = 0
    Dim linesPerPage As Integer = 0
    e.Graphics.MeasureString(_TextToPrint, TextPrintFont, e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic, charactersOnPage, linesPerPage)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(_TextToPrint, TextPrintFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic)
    _TextToPrint = _TextToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage)
    e.HasMorePages = (_TextToPrint.Length > 0)
End Sub

Private Sub TextEndPrint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintEventArgs)
    _PrintingComplete = True
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Opens a text file and prints its contents to PDF
''' </summary>
''' <param name="FullPathDocumentToPrint"></param>
''' <param name="SaveToPDFFile"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Function TextDocumentToPDF(ByVal FullPathDocumentToPrint As String, ByVal SaveToPDFFile As String) As Boolean ', Optional ByVal msWaitTime As Integer = 10000
    Dim rtnBoolean As Boolean = False
    If (FullPathDocumentToPrint <> "") Then
        Try
            _TextToPrint = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(FullPathDocumentToPrint)

            rtnBoolean = TextToPDF(_TextToPrint, SaveToPDFFile)
        Catch ex As Exception
            rtnBoolean = False
            Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End If

    Return rtnBoolean
End Function
#End Region

Private Function AppendBorder(ByVal original As Image, ByVal borderWidth As Integer) As Image
    Dim borderColor As Color = ImageBorderColor 'Color.Red
    Dim mypen As New Pen(borderColor, borderWidth * 2)
    Dim newSize As Size = New Size(original.Width + borderWidth * 2, original.Height + borderWidth * 2)

    Dim img As Bitmap = New Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)

    'g.Clear(borderColor)   
    g.DrawImage(original, New Point(borderWidth, borderWidth))
    g.DrawRectangle(mypen, 0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height)
    g.Dispose()

    Return img
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Creates a loop for a given number of seconds
''' </summary>
''' <param name="seconds"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub Stall(ByVal Seconds As Single)
    'Debug.Print(Now.ToString)
    Dim eDate As Date = Date.Now.AddSeconds(Seconds)
    While Now < eDate
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    'Debug.Print(Now.ToString)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).